# Adding launch image using LaunchScreen.storyboard in xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.ios, iphone-x, launch-screen

I am working on Xamarin.ios and using visual studio for development. I have added LaunchScreen.Storyboard for displaying launch image as i want to target new iPhoneX device as well. 
Problem that i am facing currently is, i am not able to see image on either device or simulator for launch image.

1. I cannot use LaunchImage.launchimage assets image approach as there is no placeholder available for iPhoneX for adding image in xamarin.
2. I have tried adding images in Images.xcassets folder and accessing it in storyboard. However, its just displays blank screen.
3. Also tried editing contents.json for adding iphoneX launch image, still no success.

Please let me know if anybody has faced same issue and resolved it.

Comment: In iOS 8+, Apple recommend us use LaunchScreen to configure our launch image. But do not put your image source in Assets.xcassets, I find images in this folder can't be used in storyboard in Xamarin.iOS. You can put your source in project directly and try again.

Comment: I was having a similar issue using an image in my resources folder, but using a different image worked.  I have not figured out why yet, they are both .png files of similar dimensions and size, both have lower case names, transparent backgrounds... my suggestion is to try other images.

Comment: I am having a similar issue but no luck till now if anyone found a solution for this please let me know how to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same issue today I have updated visual studio for mac with the latest version 7.4(build 1033).I am able to add the image to assets.xcassets now its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this.

having had the same problem I was finally able to select my Image set in the drop down by making sure the **Media.xcassets** folder was included in the solution.  By default it is not induced.

[image]

Once this was done a clean and rebuild allowed me to select the SplashImage Asset set in the drop down under the Image View properties.

[image]